# How do I uninstall Windows programs from Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, uninstall

Well, I've got a computer with a Windows partition, but whenever I try to boot to it once it's loaded it freezes.

I want to free some space from that partition (for example, uninstalling Windows programs), but I don't know how to do this 'safely'; that is, without damaging the other parts of the system. Do you know any way to do this?

If you could help me that would be of great help.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you have a dual boot system and your windows freezes and you thing it is because the windows partition is too small? If so, you may be can increase the windows partition, get windows running, deinstall programs and than decrease the partition again. Did you try to start windows in safe mode (with minimum driver loaded).

Comment: Just remove the windows partition and use the allocated space for Ubuntu. That saves time on manually removing everything.

Comment: @dago No, it's quite big, as it used to be my primary OS for a long time. I'll try to start windows in safe mode.

Comment: @Lekensteyn But I still have a lot of files to be classified and removed from that partition.

Comment: Do you want to keep windows as a second system or is your question how to get rid of windows to save space? Again, is it a dual boot system or did you install ubuntu inside windows using wubi install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with an Ubuntu livecd (or liveusb), mount the windows partition (or patitions) and remove or backup elsewhere files not needed to run the windows system, and that take more space, as video files, music files and so on.

You cannot, for what I know, remove correctly windows application without starting the windows system. If it freeze, probably it will freeze even if you try to start it through virtual box (thing that is difficult to setup too).